# What is the order of integration of AR + MA

Tags: autoregressive, cointegration, moving-average

Consider the following bivariate DGP for ($y_t,z_t$):

$y_t = \gamma(z_{t-1} + \theta_{21}\epsilon_{2,t-1} + u_{2,t}) + \theta_{11} \epsilon_{1,t-1} + u_{1,t} $

$z_t = z_{t-1} + \theta_{21}\epsilon_{2,t-1} + u_{2,t} $

With constraint

(i) $ 0 < \theta_{11} < 1$;

(ii) $\theta_{21} \neq 0$

The question is to discuss the I(d) of the processes and cointegration and if there exists a cointegration vector.

If we start with 
$z_t = z_{t-1} + \theta_{21}\epsilon_{2,t-1} + u_{2,t} $

One can see that we have here a AR process with a unit root $\phi = 1$ and hence I(1) for that part.
Then we still have an MA part from which we know that a finite sum of random variables is covariance stationary and hence I(0) with the conclusion that $z_t$ = I(1) and $\Delta z_t$ = I(0).

If we move on to 
$y_t = \gamma(z_{t-1} + \theta_{21}\epsilon_{2,t-1} + u_{2,t}) + \theta_{11} \epsilon_{1,t-1} + u_{1,t} $

We have $z_t$ in the equation so we have that $y_t$ is at least I(2) and if we follow my line of thought regarding that the MA part is still stationary and hence I(0) we conclude that $y_t$ = I(2) and $\Delta y_t$ = I(1).

If we change the situation and assume the following constraint

(i) $ \theta_{11} = 1$;

The MA part in $y_t$ becomes non stationary hence I(1) and then the $\Delta y_t$ becomes I(3); however I am not sure about this part.

Furthermore we conclude that $y_t$ and $z_t$ are cointegrated through the vector $[1, -\theta_{11}]'$.

I am really curious to see if my analysis is correct; thank you very much in advance. If there is any reference; kindly refer.

Comment: Hi: I can't help much ( because I don't have time and probably couldn't help much even if I did ) but $z_{t}$ is denoted as I(1) ( because of the unit root ) and it's difference is I(0). Also, there are no restrictions on MA coefficients. A pure MA process is always stationary. It's invertibility that can be an issue for an MA but that's not related to stationarity.  A good text on these concepts is Hamilton's Time Series Analysis.

Comment: Yes you are right about that indeed but in order for the model of $y_t$ to balance it must be an I(1) to

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do but $y_t$ is I(1) because it's a linear function of $z_{t}$ which is I(1). I think you're assignment  is hinting at the concept of cointegration. ? google for "engle-granger cointegration" and a lot of material will pop up. Or check out Enders test or Hamilton's text for more details on Engle Granger methodology. For two variables to be cointegrated, one necessary but not sufficient condition is that  both variables need to be I(1) and it seems that your setup satisfies that condition. The texts  will explain the other condition.

Comment: In the above, I meant Ender's text rather than Ender's test.